# Luigi Tasks going into infinite Loops

Tags: python-3.x, luigi

I have a simple luigi Task that on run will yield itself with a different parameter as shown below.

```
import luigi

class ComputeJob(luigi.Task):

   id_parameter = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()

    #run defination
    def run(self):


        print ("\nrunning task {}".format(self.id_parameter))
        #Do some work here

        if self.id_parameter < 10: 
            next_val = self.id_parameter + 1
            yield ComputeJob(id_parameter = next_val)
```

I am expecting it to run for 10 times and then exit the run but after executing the 10th iteration, it starts re-executing the 9 steps from the very start. Due to this the tasks keep looping in step 9 and 10.

so the expected out put should be :

```
running task 1
running task 2
running task 3
running task 4
running task 5
running task 6
running task 7
running task 8
running task 9
running task 10
```

but the output that i get is :

```
running task 1
running task 2
running task 3
running task 4
running task 5
running task 6
running task 7
running task 8
running task 9
running task 10
running task 9
running task 10
running task 9
running task 10
...
...
...
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks, Oyshik

Comment: So, I found that every time a Task is invoked , an `exists()`  is called on the output target. If the target is present then the task would not be re-run. I was hoping that I could do away with the output all together as my task does not produce any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the documentation for the method [complete](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.task.html#luigi.task.Task.complete) if you want to 'do away with the output all together' as you stated in your follow-up comment.

Another option would be to create an additional wrapper task to run this ComputeJob task you've created as many times as you want.

```
import luigi

class ComputeJob(luigi.Task):
  id_parameter = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()
  done = False

  #run definition
  def run(self):
    print ("\nrunning task {}".format(self.id_parameter))
    #Do some work here
    self.done = True

  def complete(self):
    if self.done:
      return True
    else:
      return False

class RunComputeJobs(luigi.WrapperTask):
  def requires(self):
    for i in range(1,10):
      yield ComputeJob(id_parameter = i)
```